# Recoger datos de un ArrayList para mostrarlos en un Spinner

Tags: android, arraylist, crud, spinner

Mi duda es la siguiente: 
Estoy haciendo un CRUD en Android y tengo un problema en el UPDATE. Como podéis ver, quiero recoger todos los datos en un Bundle y luego imprimirlos con setText() en el formulario de actualización. El problema es que el último dato, la cilindrada (que aparece comentada porque si no me da error), quiero mostrarla en un Spinner y no sé cuál es el método.

[image: Este es el código donde recojo los datos del arraylist con el Bundle]

[image: Aquí tenéis los items de mi arraylist]

[image: aquí podéis ver el problema. Me falta recoger la cilindrada que va en el spinner]

Así es como envío los datos al hacer click sobre los items de la lista:

```
listView_motocicletas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int posicion, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Listado_motocicletas.this, listado_motocicletas.get(posicion), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int clave= Integer.parseInt((listado_motocicletas.get(posicion).split(" ")[0]));
            String marca= listado_motocicletas.get(posicion).split(" ")[1];
            String matricula= listado_motocicletas.get(posicion).split(" ")[2];
            String cilindrada= listado_motocicletas.get(posicion).split(" ")[3];
            Intent intent = new Intent(Listado_motocicletas.this, Actualizar_moto.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", clave);
            intent.putExtra("marca", marca);
            intent.putExtra("matricula", matricula);
            intent.putExtra("cilindrada", cilindrada);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Y aquí es donde lo recojo:

```
Bundle b= getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (b!=null){ 
        id=b.getInt("id");
        marca=b.getString("marca");
        matricula=b.getString("matricula");
        cilindrada=b.getString("cilindrada");
    }

    marca_actualizar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.marca_actualizar);
    matricula_actualizar=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.matricula_actualizar);
    cilindrada_actualizar=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cilindrada_actualizar);
    boton_actualizar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_actualizar);
    boton_eliminar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_eliminar);

    marca_actualizar.setText(marca);
    matricula_actualizar.setText(matricula);
    //cilindrada_actualizar.getSelectedItem();
```

La cilindrada la recojo pero no puedo establecerla porque si no, me da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, considera compartir el código de lo que llevas, como texto, no como imagen

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jorge, además de lo que comenta Riaven, en el caso de Android es importante revisar el LogCat ahí te brinda más detalle relacionado al problema. Me parece que el problema es simplemente porque no envías el valor en el bundle. Agrega como realizas el envío de los datos.

Comment: Ya están los códigos añadidos. el valor sí lo envío y lo recojo con el bundle. El problema está en que con la marca y la matrícula puedo hacer un setText(), pero con la cilindrada no porque hay que meterla dentro de un spinner. Creo que tengo que usar un adaptador pero no estoy seguro.
Muchas gracias y disculpad por no haber pasado el código antes. Soy nuevo y pensé que sería más claro si lo pasaba en imágenes.

Comment: los datos que muestras en el listView provienen de una base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Hay que guardar la selección (`posicion`) del Spinner como `int`, no el `string` que contiene el item:

```
 int itemSeleccionado = cilindrada_actualizar.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Por `intent` se envia como `int`:

```
 int cilindrada= listado_motocicletas.get(posicion).split(" ")[3];
 ...
 intent.putExtra("cilindrada", cilindrada);
```

Y se obtiene igual como `int`, para mostrarlo en el `spinner` con `setSelection`, no es con `get`:

```
 int cilindrada=0;
 cilindrada=b.getInt("cilindrada");
 cilindrada_actualizar.setSelection(cilindrada);
```

Para acceder a tu array de recursos:

```
 String[] tu_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tu_spinner_array);
```

Si solo quieres mostrar el texto:

```
 tu_TextView.setText(tu_array[cilindrada]);
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que hace esta línea:

int itemSeleccionado = cilindrada_actualizar.getSelectedItemPosition();

En cuanto a esto:

int cilindrada= listado_motocicletas.get(posicion).split(" ")[3];
 ...
 intent.putExtra("cilindrada", cilindrada);

Me obliga a hacer un parseo, ya que en el spinner hay un string (no pongo solo el número d centimetros cubicos. Pongo tambien "cc". Ejemplo: "1000cc").

y lo último:

int cilindrada=0;
 cilindrada=b.getInt("cilindrada");
 cilindrada_actualizar.setSelection(cilindrada);

no me lo marca como error pero se para la app.

Comment: Muchas gracias y disculpa armen. Soy nuevo y no sé si debo seguir el hilo de las respuestas en los comentarios.

Comment: Por eso te pregunté que si los daos que muestras en el ListView vienen de una base de datos. Vas a guardar la posicion del item del spinner no el texto.

Comment: Tienes los items del spinner en recursos? o los creas dinamicamente?

Comment: sí, los daos recogen todos los registros de una base de datos. Los items de este spinner (la cilindrada) están en los recursos.

Comment: en las dos últimas imágenes puedes ver el proceso de create y read.

Comment: ok. Como te digo en la respuesta guarda la posicion del spinner (item) como int en la base de datos. Al leer obtienes ese int, y ese da la posicion de ese array